# We have $a^3+b^3$ and $ab$, how we can calculate $a+b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One of my friends is a high school student, he asked me this question. It's soluble by use of [General formula for cubic roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), because:

$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$

But he looked for a simple answer (e.g use of identities).

**Edit:** Thanks to the Travis and Andre Nicolas comments, the original question said $a^3+b^3=\frac{7}{2}$ and $ab=.75$

Comment: $a+b=x \Rightarrow x^3-abx-(a^3+b^3)=0$

Comment: @Roman83 I know, I said with out use of cubic root formula.

Comment: There's no way to improve on this, at least for general $a^3 + b^3$ and $ab$: If we relabel the given values and denote $x := a + b$, we're solving $x^3 + p x + q = 0$, but this a general depressed cubic, which is the form to which one typically reduces a general cubic when solving the general cubic equation.

Comment: The *general* cubic is reducible to this form. So one cannot do better than the "Cardano" formula, or (if we are willing to use transcendental functions) the solutions of the cubic using trig/hyperbolic functions.

Comment: @KonKan OP's problem is pretty clearly not setting up that equation, but solving it. Since this more-or-less amounts to a general cubic, finding the solution is hardly "standard high school material".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to improve on this, at least for general $a^3 + b^3$ and $ab$: If we relabel the given values and denote $x:=a+b$, we're solving $x^3 + p x + q = 0$, but this a general depressed cubic, which is the form to which one typically reduces a general cubic when solving the general cubic equation.

On the other hand, for the special values $a^3 + b^3 = \frac{7}{2}$ and $ab = \frac{3}{4}$ OP gives in the comments, the resulting equation is:
$$\tfrac{1}{4}(4 x^3 - 9 x - 14) = 0 .$$
The Rational Root Theorem gives finitely many possible rational roots, and checking them we find that $x = 2$ is a solution. Polynomial long division then gives the quadratic factor of the above cubic, but it turns out to have negative discriminant, so the other solutions are nonreal.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a simple solution in this special case.

Comment: You're welcome. In general, either there is a rational solution---in which case the method in my answer works---or there is not---in which case one has to use something equivalent to Cardano's Method.

Comment: Is there any way to find $a+b$ without use of *Rational Root Theorem* in this case? I guess because $a+b=2$ there is an easier way to find $a+b$ by only use of identities.

Comment: Well, you can attempt to fact the cubic manually by writing $(c x + d)(e x^2 + f x + g)$, expanding, and solving for coefficients, but this is a system of $4$ quadratic equations and so isn't very pleasant. It's probably best to use the R.R.T. to narrow down the possibilities. For example, a bit of meditation shows that there are no solutions $\leq 1$, leaving only $\frac{7}{4}, 2, \frac{7}{2}, 7, 14$ to check, and it's computationally least intensive to check the integer candidates first.

Comment: Furthermore, since the derivative of the cubic is $\frac{1}{4}(12 x^3 - 9)$, we can see that the function is increasing for $x \geq 1$, so there is at most one solution and we can use the value of the polynomial at one candidate to eliminate other possibilities as we go along.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_{start}=(a+b)$$
$$x_{n+1} =\sqrt{\frac{a^3+b^3}{x_n}+3ab }$$

This is not single shot operation but an iteration technique.

Start with a reasonable first iteration value of $x$. Substitute it in right hand side. Plug in the left hand side resulting value again into into right side. Repeat the iteration until input and output difference is within error limit required.

Comment: Don't you mean $x_0$ in the first line and $x_n,x_{n-1}$ in the second one?

Comment: Yes thanks, shall change it , I explained verbally assuming more suitable for pre-calculus.